# Array Passed to JavaScript Function through onClick is creating [object, object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to append data to a jquery Modal through onclick and passing array into a function is creating problem. My code is as follows:-

```
var ttlpndordsqnty = topBarData['ttlpndngordrs'].length;
var ttlpndordsdata = topBarData['ttlpndngordrs'];
$('#totalpendingtestorders').empty();
$('#totalpendingtestorders').append('<a onClick="populateWidgetInfo(\''+ttlpndordsdata+ '\')" class="count red" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#totalpndgordModal"><label >' +ttlpndordsqnty+ '</label></a>');

function populateWidgetInfo(data)
{
    console.log(data);

} //end function
```

when i click on this then the following is returned instead of array passed. Kindly help me?

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: what does `console.log(ttlpndordsdata )` give?

Comment: This is an array of 3 objects. What's your point

Comment: In this line `$('#totalpendingtestorders').append('<a onClick="populateWidgetInfo(\''+ttlpndordsdata+ '\')" class="count red" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#totalpndgordModal"><label >' +ttlpndordsqnty+ '</label></a>');` your ttlpndordsdata converts to string and passed to your function once you click. That's why your log is `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: You best [create a proper DOM `a` tag object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and assign it's `onClick` method properly through JS and then use `.appendChild()` to append it to it's parent.

Answer (score 2):

`ttlpndordsdata` is being converted to a string at attribute event handler parameter. Use  `.on()`

```
$('#totalpendingtestorders')
.on("click", "a.count", function() {
  opulateWidgetInfo(ttlpndordsdata)
})
```

Comment: I was going to answer this one :)

Comment: @Karlen Why can you not still post an Answer? Your interpretation of Question, explanation and approach could possibly contain greater detail and description of issue and solution than present Answer; and potentially be useful to OP and SO.